# Angular4 import external component with images

Tags: angular, webpack, gulp

I am trying to import from another project on github (that I own) say my_components into my project (cool_app). A component in my_components, my_navbar uses an image in its HTML template, example:

```
<img src="../../assets/images/my_logo.png" />
```

when I use this component in cool_app angular does not find and package the image:

```
<my_navbar></my_navbar>
```

The code works but the image is not found in the browser (../../assets/images/my_logo.png). Any ideas on how to have cool_app be able to use the component with its image urls AND have my_components compile and run independently? I am thinking there is something I can set in the angular config or adjust my path in the component somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img id="image" src="http://img01.ibnlive.in/ibnlive/uploads/875x584/jpg/2015/09/new-google-logo-010915.png" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should write :

```
assets/myimage.jpg
or
./assets/myimage.jpg
```